# What are the performance implications for indexing and querying when storing multiple types in a single Azure CosmosDB collection?

Tags: indexing, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

The [Shukla et al paper](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p1668-shukla.pdf) provides an overview of the high-level indexing concepts behind Azure CosmosDB (previously Azure DocumentDB).

Consider two entity types, where each has a common field on which indexing cannot be (or preferably is not) avoided (in this case *name*):

```
{ id: "1", type: "galaxy", name="Milky Way", starCoumnt=200000000000 }
{ id: "2", type: "star", name="Pistol Star", magnitute=11.828 }
```

There are many orders of magnitude more **star** entities in the collection than **galaxy** entities.

By executing the below query I would hope to find the Milky Way galaxy...

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name = "Milky Way"
```

Getting more specific about my requirements I could ensure *type* is correct...

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.type = "galaxy" AND c.name = "Milky Way"
```

It is also important to note that I created the Milky Way galaxy document after all of it's 200 billion stars.

Based on this scenario:

1. Is there a higher indexing cost for the Milky Way due to the commonality of it's field *name* with a frequently created star type?
2. Is there a higher querying cost for the Milky Way due to the same, even if *type* is specified first in the WHERE clause?
3. If either or both of these are the case, is there a reasonable mitigation aside from manually attempting to ensure field names do not clash i.e. renaming *name* to *galaxyName*?

Comment: Have you ran any tests and examined the `PopulateQueryMetrics` headers? That would not be conclusive but it could give some insight on topic.